# Show that $\mathbf{I}(\mathbf{V}(x^n, y^m)) = \langle x, y \rangle$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Show that $\mathbf{I}(\mathbf{V}(x^n, y^m)) = \langle x, y \rangle$.
>   Where $\mathbf{I}$ is the ideal, and $\mathbf{V}$ is the affine variety.

I'm not sure how to even begin on this one. I know that I need to show $\mathbf{I}(\mathbf{V}(x^n, y^m)) \subset \langle x, y \rangle$ and $\langle x, y \rangle \subset \mathbf{I}(\mathbf{V}(x^n, y^m))$.

If we start with $p \in \langle x, y \rangle$ then we know that

$$
p(x, y) = ax+by
$$

vanishes at $(0, 0)$, for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}\left[x, y\right]$.

Any hints would be appreciated ...

Comment: Theres a theorem staying that if $f_1, \dots f_2 \in k\left[x_1, \dots, x_n\right]$, then $\langle f_1, \dots f_2 \rangle \subset \mathbf{I}(\mathbf{V}(f_1, \dots, f_s))$ but I'm not suppose to use it for this question.

Comment: Is the field here $\mathbb R$ or some algebraically closed field? Doesn't your reference mention Hilbert's Nullstellensatz?

Comment: That isn't covered til a much later chapter. I'm trying to prove by definition.

Comment: Okay, sure -- I don't think we should *have* to appeal to Hilbert's result either. Will have to think for a moment, though. The $(x, y) \subset I(V(x^n, y^m))$ inclusion really ought to be doable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that doesn't use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Let $P =(x_P, y_P) \in V(x^n, y^n)$. Since $x_P^n = y_P^n = 0$ and we're doing this computation over a field, it follows that $x_P = y_P = 0$. Thus, $V(x^n, y^n) = \{(0, 0)\}$ and $(x, y) \subset I(V(x^n, y^n))$.

Let $f \in I(V(x^n, y^n))$. By the polynomial division algorithm, we have
$$
f(x, y) = xp(x, y) + q(y).
$$

Since $f(0, 0) = 0$, we have $q(0) = 0$. It follows that $q \in (y)$. We conclude that $f \in (x, y)$ and $I(V(x^n, y^n)) \subset (x, y)$.